# Get parent object using jsonpath query

Tags: javascript, json, regex, xpath, jsonpath

i have the json below:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "name": "product1",
        "details": ["lorem ipsum", [
            {
                "code": "prd1"       
            },
            {
                "code": "prd11"
            }]
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "product2",
        "details": ["lorem ipsum", [
            {
                "code": "prd2"
            },
            {
                "code": "prd22"
            }]
        ]
    }
]
```

}

and i want to retrieve the name of the product based on the code, so 
i wrote this query

```
$.data..[?(@.code=="prd1")]
```

Result:

```
[
{
    "code": "prd1"
}]
```

Expected result:

```
[{name: "product1"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move up the tree until you reach the value of a specific key.
 At first, we need to reach the first named ancestor, which is `details`, then - to get its first parent, which holds the needed `name` property.
 This can be done using `ancestor()` function and `parent()` function:

```
$.data..[?(@.code=="prd1")].ansector("details").parent()['name'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i'm using native jsonpath query (i think ansector and parent are JS functions)